# Model.findAll() only returns one of the same children

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have an application that uses **Node**, **Postgres** and **Sequelize**. Curently I have 3 models in my DB. `User`, `Customer` and `Ticket`.

**Ticket has a n:n relation with Customer and User.**

When I'm creating a new ticket I'm supposed to pass an array of two users, each with their type in the Ticket-User relation saved to the pivot table.

The problem happens when I try to set both users as the same user, meaning that in that ticket one user played the role of two. So when I try to retrieve this info, Sequelize only returns this user one time with one of the roles played, when in fact I wanted this user to be returned 2 times, each time with it's role.

Here is how I made the query to create a new Ticket (**Note that the `users` field has the user with id 1, playing the OFFICE and INSPECTION role**):

[image]

Here is how it is created using Sequelize:

```
const {
      interested,
      opening_date,
      office_status,
      inspection_status,
      subject,
      external_code,
      conclusion_method,
      obs,
      users,
      customer_id,
      is_owner
    } = req.body;

    try {
      const ticket = await Ticket.create({
        interested,
        opening_date,
        office_status,
        inspection_status,
        subject,
        external_code,
        conclusion_method,
        obs
      });

      if (users && users.length > 0) {
        users.forEach(({ id, type }) => {
          ticket.addUser(id, { through: { type } });
        });
      }

      if (customer_id && is_owner) {
        ticket.addCustomer(customer_id, { through: { is_owner } });
      }

      if (ticket) {
        res.status(200).json({ MSG: "SAVE_SUCCESS" });
      } else {
        throw new Error({ err: "Ticket was not created" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.errors && error.errors.length >= 1) {
        let errResponse = {};
        error.errors.map(err => {
          errResponse = { ...errResponse, [err.path]: err.message };
        });
        res.status(200).json({ err: errResponse });
        return;
      }
      res.status(500).json(error);
    }
  }
```

And it works fine, if I manually check the table in the DB it shows the user with ID 1 listed twice, one time with each role.

[image]

The problem arises when I try to query it, here is how I am doing it:

```
const tickets = await Ticket.findAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: User,
            attributes: ["id", "fname", "lname", "username", "email"],
            through: { model: TicketsUsers, attributes: ["type"] }
          },
          {
            model: Customer,
            attributes: ["id", "name", "document"],
            through: { model: TicketsCustomer, attributes: ["is_owner"] }
          }
        ]
      });

      if (tickets) {
        res.status(200).json(tickets);
      } else {
        throw new Error({ err: "EMPTY" });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
```

It works when different users are assigned to each role, however when the same user is assigned to both roles, this is what gets returned:

[image]

**As you can see, the `users` field only lists user with id 1 one time, using the role `OFFICE`, when it should have listed user with id 1 two times one with each role it played on that ticket.**

Like I said this only happens when I assign the same user for both roles, if different users are used for each role, then the query returns both users in the `users`field as expected, which led me to believe the code is right, I even turned on Sequelize logging and manually executed the query it returned, and sure enough both users where returned on that query. So it is doing something internally that makes a user with same id only appear once.

I have found a similar issue here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7541

However the problem there was a missing id on one of his tables, which is not my case. All my tables have unique IDs.

So anyone knows why is this happening and how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Two suggestions that might be worth trying: in your include for the User model add `separate: true`, so you have `{model: User, separate: true, ...}`. Alternatively try `right: true`. If either of these work then I can put a proper answer with an explanation.

Comment: @braza Thanks for the reply, unfortunately, none of the options worked. Apparently using `separate: true` is only valid for the `hasMany` relation and `right: true` did not change anything.

Comment: @AlexandreKrabbe, I think `raw : true` shall solve your problem

Comment: @SohamLawar Thank you for the reply, the suggestion you proposed did not solve the problem. It only made all the columns show up, but the user still only appear once.